# Xtermjs can not copy & paste

Tags: angular, typescript, xtermjs

I was not able to implement the copy & paste function from xterm.js APIs. I want the terminal to be able to copy strings from the clipboard.

I'm using

```
  this.term.onKey((key) => {
    if (key.domEvent.code === 'KeyC'){
     if (key.domEvent.ctrlKey) {
     this.copiedText = this.term.getSelection();
    }
   } else if (key.domEvent.code === 'KeyV'){
     if (key.domEvent.ctrlKey) {
     this.term.write(this.copiedText);
    } 
   }
  }
```

but it can only get copied text within the terminal and the key event can not detect the command key on MAC (right now I'm using ctl + c & ctl + v)

If I use the onData(), the event is triggered when I press command + V and I can see it outputs strings ouside the terminal

```
  this.term.onData((data) => {
    console.log(data.toString());  // prints "strings I copied with command + c"
  });
```

But "data" is just a string and the event is triggered by key press as well, so term.onData will conflict with onKey() event, and I'm not sure how to set a condition on "data" since it is not a object.

Comment: can you post bit more typescript code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Terminal.attachCustomKeyEventHandler`](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/blob/70babeacb62fe05264d64324ca1f4436997efa1b/typings/xterm.d.ts#L538-L547) for ctrl/cmd+c/v to intercept the key press and prevent it from being evaluated by the terminal.

In that handler you can handle the keypress and use the relevant web APIs to copy and paste the text (`document.execCommand` or preferably [`navigator.clipboard`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/clipboard)).

Comment: Example here: https://github.com/GNS3/gns3-web-ui/blob/master/src/app/components/project-map/web-console/web-console.component.ts#L72-L79

Answer (score 0):

Few things.

1. onKey doesn't capture mac's CMD key, for that you need [attachCustomKeyEventHandler](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/blob/70babeacb62fe05264d64324ca1f4436997efa1b/typings/xterm.d.ts#L538-L547)
2. Good news is you can use both onKey and `attachCustomKeyEventHandler` together, so I normally use `attachCustomKeyEventHandler` to capture Mac's CMD events and other Control Keys and use onKey for anything else.
3. You can read/write to the clipboard using the [navigator.clipboard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/clipboard) APIs. e.g `const clipboardText = await navigator.clipboard.readText();`
4. One last note, selection and copy works out of the box for me, I only have code for paste. Using clipboard API also means you can copy from outside the terminal and paste in terminal.